# Sequelize onDelete CASCADE is not working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am building a Node JS application. I am using Sequelize for the database. I am having a problem with onDelete Cascase rule in the database.

I have a model called Team and the following is the migration file for the team:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Teams', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      status: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      //TODO: remove this because there is many to many relationship
      game_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull : false,
        references: {
          model: "Games",
          key: "id"
        },
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
        onDelete: "CASCADE"
      },
      creator_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull : false,
        references: {
          model: "Users",
          key: "id"
        },
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
        onDelete: "CASCADE"
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Teams');
  }
};
```

Then I have a mother table with the following migration:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('GameTeams', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      team_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull : false,
        references: {
          model: "Teams",
          key: "id"
        },
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
        onDelete: "CASCADE"
      },
      game_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull : false,
        references: {
          model: "Games",
          key: "id"
        },
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
        onDelete: "CASCADE"
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('GameTeams');
  }
};
```

As you can see I set onDelete to CASCADE to make sure that the relation is deleted when the team gets deleted.

Then I run the following query to delete a team:

```
await database.sequelize.query('DELETE FROM "Teams" WHERE "id"=:id', {
      replacements: {
        id: teamResult.data.id
      },
      type: QueryTypes.DELETE
    })
```

When I run the code, I got the following error:

```
update or delete on table "Teams" violates foreign key ' +
        'constraint "GameTeams_team_id_fkey" on table "GameTeams"
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: What database are you using? What did this migrations create in the database?

Comment: remove constraints in database or whole of it, and re-create using migration and see what happens.